# Couldn't debug android app in Xiomi redmi4?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to debug my android app on my xiomi redmi4 phone.
I am getting this error while running app.[image: error]

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest me.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you press ok button ?

Comment: Just follow instructions, Uninstall app and rebuild app.

Comment: @FarazAhmed It does nothing.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn off MIUI Optimization inside Developer Options. Reboot it and run android app

Answer (score 2):

If you had tried all above options(USB debugging should be ON,
Install via USB should be ON) then, Go to the developer setting, then find the option **[Trun on MIUI optimization](http://en.miui.com/thread-238014-1-1.html)**, 
[image]
trun it off then restart the device, hope it will work!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall the app from your phone, Before debugging and when you click Run in android studio should click allow your phone to install the app.
it happen when there is changes in build gradle
I had same issue with Mi note 2

Comment: As your error shows that "This Issue can be resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk "
which mean app is already Installed on your phone to Uninstall
go to Setting >Installed apps>Downloaded and search your app when click on it there will option to uninstall.

Comment: I am debugging it for the first time in my redmi phone.

Comment: Ok
then replug it and when you are debugging it you have to click allow on your phone to install app it has a 10sec timer or it will automatically reject it from installing it

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced that kind of problems.

just follow the steps

Goto your mobile setting menu ---> Additional settings ---> Developer options --->

1. Developer mode should be ON
2. USB debugging should be ON
3. Install via USB should be ON

After done this steps, You can able to run your app via USB.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your device is attached to debugger and there is already app installed so you need to remove existing application using adb command in CMD so follow these steps:

1. go to SDK and sdk\platform-tools in cmd
2. adb uninstall com.app.package (package of your application)
3. Now redeploy the app, your app will be installed and you will be able to debug app.